# Atom10FeedFormatter.WriteTo() - omit values

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm using an Atom10FeedFormatter to generate a web service response but I need a way to be able to omit values.

I can set the EmitDefaultValue value like so...

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)] public string PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

which works fine in most cases as I can set values to null and they are omitted, but sometimes I need to send a null/default value...?

I've seen that with the XmlSerializer you can set a PropertyNameSpecified field which exclude/ixclude the PropertyName from the output - this there some why to do this with Atom10FeedFormatter?